Segmentation fault for android emulator inside a docker as non-root user
I am struggling to run an android emulator inside a container when I'm a non-root user.
I have alternatives but I really wonder what is happening...
Here is the setup I have developed https://github.com/nicos44k/android-emulator-docker
Move to directory then.

Build the container: ./docker_build.sh
Run the container: ./docker_run.sh
Then, in the container, run the emulator: ./emulator_run

I got a Segmentation fault (core dumped) exit (see full log here).
Some infos:

It works if I run an android emulator on my host as non-root user.
It works if you run it on the container as root: ./docker_run.sh root then ./emulator_run (see log here).
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on x86_64 architecture.
I tried on three different devices and problem is always the same.
I am able to extract android crashdata Storing crashdata in: ... (see full log).

Do you see what is the problem ?
Thank you in advance :)
